# Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

During the Project compilation with - npm start - of React i am getting this error.

```bash
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../PopperUnstyled' in 'C:\Users\pa\node_modules\@mui\base\MenuUnstyled'
ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/base/MenuUnstyled/MenuUnstyled.js 11:0-47


ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/base/MultiSelectUnstyled/MultiSelectUnstyled.js 10:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../PopperUnstyled' in 'C:\Users\pa\node_modules\@mui\base\MultiSelectUnstyled'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/base/SelectUnstyled/SelectUnstyled.js 10:0-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../PopperUnstyled' in 'C:\Users\pa\node_modules\\@mui\base\SelectUnstyled'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/base/index.js 35:0-61
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './PopperUnstyled' in 'C:\Users\pa\node_modules\@mui\base'


ERROR in ./node_modules/@mui/material/Popper/Popper.js 4:0-54
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mui/base/PopperUnstyled' in 'C:\Users\pa\node_modules\@mui\material\Popper'

webpack compiled with 5 errors
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, lstat 'C:\Users\pa\node_modules\@mui\base\PopperUnstyled'
```

I have tried to solve this problem with the installation of these modules, but not able to resolve it:

```
npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons
```